# Python CLI Keeps Performing the Same Command?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-idle

I'm trying to create a command line that will allow a user to perform various functions.
For example, if I type "scriptrun" into the terminal, I want it to run a function from another .py file, and then return to the terminal (->>).
For some reason, if I type "scriptrun", it will run properly, but then if I hit "enter" again, it will cause the command to be run again.  I'm basing it off a Turtle CLI that I found.  After I enter help, I want it to show the list of help topics only once, and then if I keep hitting enter, it will just show the terminal, but the following is happening!:

(Terminal) help

## Documented commands (type help ):

bye     color    goto     help  left      position  reset  scriptrun
circle  forward  heading  home  playback  record    right  undo

(Terminal) [Here i just hit enter, but below you can see it's calling the help function again!]

## Documented commands (type help ):

bye     color    goto     help  left      position  reset  scriptrun
circle  forward  heading  home  playback  record    right  undo

(Terminal)

Below is the sample code that I am trying to figure out the solution to:

```
import cmd, sys
from turtle import *
from orion_package import *

class TurtleShell(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to the turtle shell.   Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = '(Terminal) '
    file = None


    # ----- basic turtle commands -----
    def do_forward(self, arg):
        'Move the turtle forward by the specified distance:  FORWARD 10'
        forward(*parse(arg))
    def do_right(self, arg):
        'Turn turtle right by given number of degrees:  RIGHT 20'
        right(*parse(arg))
    def do_left(self, arg):
        'Turn turtle left by given number of degrees:  LEFT 90'
        left(*parse(arg))
    def do_goto(self, arg):
        'Move turtle to an absolute position with changing orientation.  GOTO 100 200'
        goto(*parse(arg))
    def do_home(self, arg):
        'Return turtle to the home postion:  HOME'
        home()
    def do_circle(self, arg):
        'Draw circle with given radius an options extent and steps:  CIRCLE 50'
        circle(*parse(arg))
    def do_position(self, arg):
        'Print the current turle position:  POSITION'
        print('Current position is %d %d\n' % position())
    def do_heading(self, arg):
        'Print the current turle heading in degrees:  HEADING'
        print('Current heading is %d\n' % (heading(),))
    def do_color(self, arg):
        'Set the color:  COLOR BLUE'
        color(arg.lower())
    def do_undo(self, arg):
        'Undo (repeatedly) the last turtle action(s):  UNDO'
    def do_reset(self, arg):
        'Clear the screen and return turtle to center:  RESET'
        reset()
    def do_bye(self, arg):
        'Stop recording, close the turtle window, and exit:  BYE'
        print('Thank you for using Turtle')
        self.close()
        bye()
        return True


    # ----- record and playback -----
    def do_record(self, arg):
        'Save future commands to filename:  RECORD rose.cmd'
        self.file = open(arg, 'w')
    def do_playback(self, arg):
        'Playback commands from a file:  PLAYBACK rose.cmd'
        self.close()
        with open(arg) as f:
            self.cmdqueue.extend(f.read().splitlines())
    def precmd(self, line):
        line = line.lower()
        if self.file and 'playback' not in line:
            print(line, file=self.file)
        return line
    def close(self):
        if self.file:
            self.file.close()
            self.file = None

    def do_scriptrun(self, arg):
        'Run the script: SCRIPTRUN'
        print("Let's run this thing!  :)")
        scriptrun()


def parse(arg):
    'Convert a series of zero or more numbers to an argument tuple'
    return tuple(map(int, arg.split()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TurtleShell().cmdloop()
```

Any help or advice for a solution is greatly appreciated!  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the best solution is to simply make your own version of cmd such that you modify this condition and from here you include this with your project and import it and this way you can have it just repeat the (Terminal): every time you hit enter rather than repeating the last command!

Comment: Was thinking the same thing. What I ended up doing was taking cmd, modifying it as cmd2 in my work directory, then changing the return statement for emptyline to being the following:: `if self.lastcmd: return []` A simple fix! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> help (cmd)
```

The fourth item listed is

"Typing an empty line repeats the last command".

So this is behaving as documented.

Comment: hmm thanks for pointing this out, Jon. Is there any possible way to work around this, perhaps without having to modify the cmd file?

Comment: actually, it is not repeating the last command for all cases.  For example, when I try doing reset or color BLUE for example, this is not the case!...hmmm

Comment: You'd like to have it ignore a blank line? Well, I have never worked with cmd before, but looking at the documentation, I see there are some hooks you might be able to use. I'm optimistic about the emptyline() hook in particular. :)  http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html

Comment: Yeah the goal is basically to just have it repeat indefinitely: (Terminal): (Terminal): (Terminal):
Until I stop entering empty lines.  Thanks, will check it out!

Comment: No, thank you! I'd not come across the cmd library before, it looks quite useful!